# Bootstrap Responsive Carousel doesn't resize properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I have a carousel under my navbar.

It works OK on normal computers, check [this link](http://bit.ly/WZCQHR).

However, I'm having trouble on smaller screens, e.g. iPhone. Just resize your browser screen to see what I mean.

I'm figuring maybe it isn't necessary the responsive CSS but something else I' doing wrong. Maybe their are better ways to get the carousel image with resized on every screen.

Also, I would like the carousel to have a 100% height of the screen, so the carousel spans the entire screen, and the rest of the content shows only when you scroll.

CSS I'm using:

```
      /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-top: -80px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel .container {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 9;
}    

.carousel-control {
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 120px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
  min-height: 800px;
}

.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: static;
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.carousel-caption2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: static;
  max-width: 380px;
  padding: 200px 20px;
}

.carousel-caption h1,
.carousel-caption .lead,
.carousel-caption2 h1,
.carousel-caption2 .lead {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.carousel-caption .btn,
.carousel-caption2 .btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#wrapper-container {
margin-bottom: -80px;
padding-bottom: 80px;
position: relative;
background: inherit;
top: 60%;
}

/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}
.featurette {
  padding-top: 120px; /* Vertically center images part 1: add padding above and below text. */
  overflow: hidden; /* Vertically center images part 2: clear their floats. */
}
.featurette-image {
  margin-top: -120px; /* Vertically center images part 3: negative margin up the image the same amount of the padding to center it. */
}

/* Give some space on the sides of the floated elements so text doesn't run right into it. */
.featurette-image.pull-left {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.featurette-image.pull-right {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}



/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 979px) {

  .container.navbar-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
  .navbar-inner {
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .carousel .item {
    min-height: 500px;
  }

  .carousel img {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .featurette {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .featurette-image.pull-left,
  .featurette-image.pull-right {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    max-width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
  }
}

 @media (max-width: 767px) {

  .navbar-inner {
    margin: -20px;
  }

  .carousel {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
  }
  .carousel .container {

  }
  .carousel .item {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .carousel img {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    width: 65%;
    padding: 0 70px;
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  .carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-caption .lead,
  .carousel-caption .btn {
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .featurette .lead {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot you would need to do to clean it up... The following will get you started, but there would definitely be a bit more tweaking to do.

I didn't look at the CSS to fill the screen with an image as per your last request. I think you will have to look at adding a different carousel with other cropped images with a portrait aspect ratio if you want that, so you show the specific part of the image you want.

Firstly under `@media (max-width: 767px)`, remove:

```
  .navbar-inner {
    margin: -20px;
  }
```

It's causing your menu bar at the top to shift up out of sight.

From `@media... .carousel`, remove:

```
 margin-left: -20px;
 margin-right: -20px;
```

This is messy, and is there because of the padding added to body (see below).

Add the following to `@media (max-width... .carousel`:

```
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0px;
```

Because you want the carousel to sit neatly under the navbar.

Remove the following from `@media... body`

```
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
```

This is causing problems for the carousel, and you can add this padding for specific divs like `wrapper-container` if you want.

From `.carousel img`, remove:

```
 margin-top: -200px;
```

Next, you have to fix the fact that the text under the carousel is moved way down:

Add the following to `@media... #wrapper-container`

```
 top: 0;
```

Remove the following from `@media (max-width: 979px)`

```
.carousel .item {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

and the following from `@media (max-width: 767px)`

```
.carousel img {
    height: 300px;
}
```

because the carousel is nowhere near that height at smartphone sizes.

You will also have to play around with the positioning of the caption text in the @media CSS. You may want to decide to lose some caption text as the carousel shrinks.

This will get you started, and you can go from there...

Comment: Thanks will check it tomorrow

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply. Doesn't fix the problem though, check the link in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, get rid of the  margin-top: -200px;  on your .corousel img style.
With a small screen, your image height is less than 200px and this causes it to go off of the screen.

Comment: That's being overwritten at the end in the CSS right in the responsive part?