# how to create a responsive carousel

Tags: html, css

I want to create a carousel(class="carousel-inner ") and display an icon(class="scroll-icon") into it. But I cannot make it responsive so the icon's position cannot be responsive. how to make a responsive carousel-inner?

> large screen

[image: icon on large screen]

> small screen(blue area belongs to carousel-inner)

[image: size of carousel on small screen]

```html
<div class="home">

        <div class="banner">

            <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide d-none d-md-block " data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner " style="height: 1300px ">
                    <div class="carousel-item active" data-aos="fade-in">
                        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" data-aos="fade-down" src="{{asset('images/home/deneme.jpg')}}" alt="First slide" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item" data-aos="fade-in">
                        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" data-aos="fade-in" src="{{asset('images/home/carousel2.jpg')}}" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item" data-aos="fade-in">
                        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" data-aos="fade-in" src="{{asset('images/home/carousel3-2.jpg')}}" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        

            <img class="scroll-icon" style="position: absolute; z-index: 999999999999; left: 50%; top:700px" src="{{asset("/images/scroll.svg")}}"/>

        </div>
```

Comment: there are lots of tutorials related to this, have a look at this one https://css-tricks.com/creating-responsive-touch-friendly-carousels-with-flickity/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Responsive Carousel doesn't resize properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842044/bootstrap-responsive-carousel-doesnt-resize-properly)

Comment: Here is a responsive example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Change `top:700px` to `bottom: 0` on your icon's `style` attribute:

`<img class="scroll-icon" style="position: absolute; z-index: 999999999999; left: 50%; bottom: 0" src="{{asset("/images/scroll.svg")}}"/>`

Have in mind that this will move your scroll icon to the bottom of the .banner div.